# Convert Degrees Minutes Seconds coordinates to decimal in Android

Tags: android, gps, android-mapview

I have a database with coordinates in Degrees Minutes Seconds format, is there any way to change them to decimal coordinates using Android built in function or is there any simpler way to show such coordinates in a mapview ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

minutes and seconds are just base 60, decimals would be

```
theDegees = degrees+ minutes /60 + seconds/(60*60)
```

mind the integer ops